# Angular not working because of MIME error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I moved [from this site](https://wp-testi.gromi.fi) to [here](https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/) and inspector says this: Failed to instantiate module app due to:

```html
Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/nomod?p0=app
    at https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:24:186
    at a (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:23:252)
    at https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:23:495
    at https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:37:427
    at m (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:7:322)
    at h (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:37:275)
    at fb (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:41:35)
    at d (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:19:463)
```

```
at zc (https://kukamedia.fi-h.seravo.com/js/angular.min.js:20:274
```

Comment: show us code of your server. what you use to serve your bundles ?

Comment: edit your index.html and remove the @v=x.x from all your <script src="js/logout.js@v=2.0"></script> files.  logout.js@v=2.0 to logout.js

Comment: Or change `@` to `?`